# What is the difference between "API" and "input" toggling of toggle button in bootstrap-toggle?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

In an example of [Bootstrap toggle button](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) control, there are two examples of turning them on and off: by API and by input.

Section "API vs Input":

```
<input id="toggle-trigger" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="toggleOn()">On by API</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="toggleOff()">Off by API</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="toggleOnByInput()">On by Input</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="toggleOffByInput()">Off by Input</button>
<script>
  function toggleOn() {
    $('#toggle-trigger').bootstrapToggle('on')
  }
  function toggleOff() {
    $('#toggle-trigger').bootstrapToggle('off')  
  }
  function toggleOnByInput() {
    $('#toggle-trigger').prop('checked', true).change()
  }
  function toggleOffByInput() {
    $('#toggle-trigger').prop('checked', false).change()
  }
</script>
```

As one can see, operating button by API means calling `bootstrapToogle()` function, while operating by input means calling `prop('checked', true).change()`.

What is the difference between these two methods? Visually they do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference I see is that you can change a checkbox using `prop()` and not have to know it is bound to a plugin.

If the plugin was removed ... behavior wouldn't change on the underlying input if you always used `prop()`.

Conversely, adding the plugin on top of existing code wouldn't require code changes either.

I think author's intent was to show that the plugin recognizes `change` event when triggered externally

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapToggle handles a bit more than just changing the property:

```
Toggle.prototype.on = function (silent) {
    if (this.$element.prop('disabled')) return false
    this.$toggle.removeClass(this._offstyle + ' off').addClass(this._onstyle)
    this.$element.prop('checked', true)
    if (!silent) this.trigger()
}

Toggle.prototype.off = function (silent) {
    if (this.$element.prop('disabled')) return false
    this.$toggle.removeClass(this._onstyle).addClass(this._offstyle + ' off')
    this.$element.prop('checked', false)
    if (!silent) this.trigger()
}
```

From what I can tell, it's to add separate classes for on/off states when using bootstrapToggle, whereas otherwise you'd have to use CSS to check if the element is checked. That's really the only difference I can find, so it shouldn't make much of a difference except for the way you style the toggles.